# Menu bar on left goes away in navigating using places and activities

Tags: java, gwt

In my application I want to keep the menu on the left on all the pages, but when I click on the button on the left, my menu goes away. I am attaching my code here.

Launcher class:

```
public class SmartEBRM implements EntryPoint {

//private Place defaultPlace = new SmartEBRMViewPlace("World!");
//private SimplePanel appWidget = new SimplePanel();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ClientFactory clientFactory = GWT.create(ClientFactory.class);
    EventBus eventBus = clientFactory.getEventBus();
    PlaceController placeController = clientFactory.getPlaceController();

    // Start ActivityManager for the main widget with our ActivityMapper
    ActivityMapper activityMapper = new AppActivityMapper(clientFactory);
    ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(activityMapper, eventBus);
    SmartEBRMViewImpl smartViewImpl = new SmartEBRMViewImpl();
    activityManager.setDisplay (smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel());


    // Start PlaceHistoryHandler with our PlaceHistoryMapper
    AppPlaceHistoryMapper historyMapper= GWT.create(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
    PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(historyMapper);
    SmartEBRMViewPlace smartViewPlace = new SmartEBRMViewPlace();
    //ClearPannelPlace smartViewPlace = new ClearPannelPlace();
    historyHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, smartViewPlace);
    historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();

    RootPanel.get().add(smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel());
}
}
```

Main View:

```
public class SmartEBRMViewImpl extends Composite implements SmartEBRMView{

private static SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder.class);

@UiField DockLayoutPanel docLayoutPanel;
@UiField StackPanel stackPanel;
@UiField Button enterpriseView;
@UiField Button testComponent;
@UiField SimplePanel centerPanel;
@UiField SimplePanel westPanel;
@UiField SimplePanel northPanel;

private Presenter listener;

interface SmartEBRMViewImplUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, SmartEBRMViewImpl> {
}

public SmartEBRMViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

public SmartEBRMViewImpl(String firstName) {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(Presenter listener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.listener = listener;

}

public SimplePanel getHTMLPannel () {
    return centerPanel;
}

public SimplePanel getNorthPanel () {
    return northPanel;
}

public SimplePanel getWestPanel () {
    return westPanel;
}

@UiHandler("enterpriseView")
public void onClearButtonClick(ClickEvent e)
{
    listener.goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
}
```

this is where I go to.. with the left side constant:

```
public class EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImpl extends Composite implements EnterpriseInvoiceCompareView{

private static EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImplUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImplUiBinder.class);
@UiField VerticalPanel verticalPannel;
@UiField HorizontalPanel invoiceNumberPanel;
@UiField Label invoiceNumberLabel;
@UiField TextBox invoiceNumberBox;
private Presenter listener;


interface EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImplUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImpl> {
}

public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewImpl() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(Presenter listener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Activity:

```
public class SmartEBRMViewActivity extends AbstractActivity implements
SmartEBRMView.Presenter {

private ClientFactory clientFactory;

public SmartEBRMViewActivity(SmartEBRMViewPlace place, ClientFactory clientFactory) {
    //this.place = place;
    this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SmartEBRMView smartEBRMView = clientFactory.getSmartEBRMView();
    smartEBRMView.setPresenter(this);
    containerWidget.setWidget(smartEBRMView.asWidget());

}

@Override
public void goTo(Place place) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(place);
}

}

public class EnterpriseInvoiceCompareActivity extends AbstractActivity implements EnterpriseInvoiceCompareView.Presenter{

private ClientFactory clientFactory;

public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareActivity(EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace place, ClientFactory clientFactory) {
    //this.name = place.getHelloName();
    this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EnterpriseInvoiceCompareView entInvoiceCompareView = clientFactory.getEnterpriseInvoiceCompareView();
    entInvoiceCompareView.setPresenter(this);
    containerWidget.setWidget(entInvoiceCompareView.asWidget());
}

@Override
public void goTo(Place place) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(place);
}

}
```

Mapper:

```
public class AppActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper{

private ClientFactory clientFactory;

/**
 * AppActivityMapper associates each Place with its corresponding
 * {@link Activity}
 * 
 * @param clientFactory
 *            Factory to be passed to activities
 */
public AppActivityMapper(ClientFactory clientFactory) {
    super();
    this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

/**
 * Map each Place to its corresponding Activity. This would be a great use
 * for GIN.
 */
@Override
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (place instanceof EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace){
        return new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareActivity((EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace) place, clientFactory);
    }
    else if (place instanceof SmartEBRMViewPlace)
        return new SmartEBRMViewActivity((SmartEBRMViewPlace) place, clientFactory);

    return null;
}

}
```

Place:

```
public class EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace extends Place{

public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace()
{
}

public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace>
{

    @Override
    public String getToken(EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace place)
    {
        return "EntInvoiceCompare";
    }

    @Override
    public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace getPlace(String token)
    {
        return new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace();
    }

}

}

public class SmartEBRMViewPlace extends Place{

public SmartEBRMViewPlace()
{
}

public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<SmartEBRMViewPlace>
{

    @Override
    public String getToken(SmartEBRMViewPlace place)
    {
        return "SmartView";
    }

    @Override
    public SmartEBRMViewPlace getPlace(String token)
    {
        return new SmartEBRMViewPlace();
    }

}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static menu on the left, then either it should not be an activity (it can still react to `PlaceChangeEvent` events if needed) or you should have 2 `ActivityManager`s for the left region (with an `ActivityMapper` that always returns your menu activity whichever the place) and the center region (with an `ActivityMapper` that returns the appropriate activity depending on the current place).

---

BTW, I find it strange that your add the `smartViewImpl.getHTMLPannel()` to the `RootPanel`, and not the `smartViewImpl`.

Comment: I added smartViewImpl initially but then I get two menus on the left. If I click on one of these, I get to the second page, and if I click on the leftmost one, it does nothing.

Comment: I haven't looked at all your code, because there's just too much of it. I suspect that you haven't totally grasped all things should be laid out and organized, so I can only give you an advice. Have a look at [my blog](http://blog.ltgt.net/) too, I posted some articles about places and activities that might help you understand all this.

Comment: Can you please suggest what code should I put, so you can suggest a solution? I am new to GWT, and "places and activities" totally confused me.